# Slapping sound coming from wheel

Tags: tires, noise, car, wheels

When driving, I noticed that a slapping sound was coming from my rear passenger-side wheel. The tempo of the slapping sound would accelerate and decelerate as the car's speed increased and decreased.

I replaced my wheel with a spare after reading this article since it suggested that the tire tread might be separating.

https://www.complex.com/sports/2014/07/10-car-noises-and-what-they-mean/slapping

After I replaced the wheel, the slapping sound went away. However, I didn't notice any bulges on the wheel that would indicate tread separation.

Could this really be a case of tire tread separation? Or might it be something else?

Comment: It may be internal to the tire...

Comment: You should probably check your tires, this is one of the common reasons why you are hearing a slapping sound.

Answer (score -1):

It may possibly be a bent wheel rim. It is common for the tyre to be suspect at first but it maybe something else. Perhaps have the wheel put on a balancing machine. You can check the tyre properly this way, then check the inner wheel rim for any bent areas. Even a slightly bent or damaged inner rim can cause a tyre to bounce on the road which gives a sort of pattering sound.

Comment: In the second paragraph the OP says.. "I replaced my 'WHEEL' with a spare". Then in the third paragraph the OP says.. "After I replaced the WHEEL'.